# Jssor slider 100% width

Tags: slider, width, jssor

I try to get a [jssor](http://www.jssor.com/) slider working with 100% width (the container has a width of 70%).
The problem is, that jssor only works with pixels, so if I use a slide_container with a width of 100%, the slider doesn't work any more. Is there any trick how to get this working?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

size of 'slide_container' should be always specified with fixed pixels.
the original size is fixed then, but you can scale the slider to any size.

use following code to scale the slider to width of document.body.

```js
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (bodyWidth)
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
ScaleSlider();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

also, you can scale the slider to width of parent element,

```js
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (parentWidth)
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 1920));
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
ScaleSlider();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

Comment: This is now part of the "Full Width Slider" demo, right ?

Comment: Yes, it is part of 'full width slider'.

Comment: How do you adjust the size on this guy?  http://www.jssor.com/demos/nested-slider.html

Comment: @jssor, i know this thead is quite old but i need help.. i feel like i've tried everything.

Comment: it is with a parent slider and 3 child sliders. You can adjust size for each separately. If there is still problem, please ask a new question in details, I will workout a demo for you.

Comment: is it also possible to change the height?

Comment: To scale, it will always keep aspect ratio. You can call jssor_slider1.$ScaleHeight instead of jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth.

Comment: I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Slide.$ScaleWidth is not a function". I am using jssor.slider.mini.js right now. Is there anything other scripts that i should be using? to get $ScalWidth to work?

Comment: jssor.slider.mini.js is enough. Is it the latest version? Do you get the slider work already?

Comment: Hey there. Can I kindly know how I can implement this in jssor wordpress? Regards

Answer (score 7):

> jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));

This still limit slider to just 1920 pix wide, maximum. So at my big screen slider was not covering 100% wide. So you may need to change that 1920 to something bigger number. I did with 19200 (one zero at the end fixed all). Once I adjusted that value it now strech all the width of my screen too.

Answer (score 3):

Using Bootstrap, if you have Jssor inside an `X` column `div`, e.g., `col-lg-12`:

```
jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(
   Math.max(
      Math.min
       (parseInt($(".col-lg 12").css("width").replace("px", "")) -  
       (parseInt($(".col-lg-12").css("padding-left").replace("px", "")) + 
       parseInt($(".col-lg-12").css("padding-right").replace("px","")))),100));
```

Answer (score 1):

As someone noticed, there is a problem when the slider's width is lesser than its parent's width. Chrome uses the maximum size of the slider, Firefox uses the parent instead.
I have found a better code, so the slider will stretch to full width. You can modify it slightly to use the parent width or the window width.

[How can I make JSSOR change its aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472909/how-can-i-make-jssor-change-its-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes looking for $ResizeCanvas. They've finally added a function that can help get the required slider size with $ScaleSize. Thanks jssor

> For the latest version 25.2.0, we added a new method $ScaleSize(width,
>   height) instead of $ResizeCanvas.

(this was first posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971633/4410051))