# JSSOR slider will not stay positioned properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jssor

I'm using Jssor slider and have gone through the posts regarding making it responsive and have it set to be the full width of the screen. My issue is that as it expands and enlarges it over laps the header as well as the content below. When you look at the example/sample at http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.html it stays pushed up against the header and the content below moves down as needed. My code is already the same in this post:
[Jssor Slider: Responsive Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309518/jssor-slider-responsive-code/23310189#23310189)
I dont mind doing more research but looking for a few ideas what to look for'as I feel like Im searching for the wrong things.   :S

Comment: Would you leave the url of your slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the post you referred is full screen slider, you may just need a full screen slider.

[download jssor slider](http://www.jssor.com/download.html) and open 'demos-jquery\full-width-slider.source.html'

Comment: This definitely was the issue, I tried to get away with the minimal code but when I used the full code from the demo you suggested it worked perfect!