# Scale full-width-slider till to the browsers bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jssor

I have a two body divs: The first one is for navigation and the second one is the "slider1_container" from jssor.

Now my Problem is that i want to scale the "slider1_container" till to the bottom like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350831/jssor-full-height-or-full-screen-slider-possible), but not in full-screen.

My code is:

```
// HTML

<div id="nav">
    <div class="nav-bar">
        ...
    </div>
</div>

<!-- SLIDER CODE -->
<!-- http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.html -->
<div id="slider1_container">
    ...
</div>



// CSS

#nav
{
    min-width: 900px;
    height: 100px;

}
...
```

Any advice?

Comment: So basically you want the answer that was posted in the linked question, but instead of full width constrain it to the width of `#nav`?

Comment: @AdamMerrifield In the linked question the slider is the only div in body and  it is in width and height maximized to the browser window. I want it also maximized to the browser window but i already have an div(with id=nav) above the sliders div with a height given in pixels.

Comment: There is a full screen slider demo.

Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472909/how-can-i-make-jssor-change-its-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a full screen slider demo.

Please see the answer of [How can I make JSSOR change its aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472909/how-can-i-make-jssor-change-its-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'bottom'?

If you mean the screen's bottom, then

```
var height = $(window).height();
```

If you mean the height of the entire page (with scrolling), then,

```
var height = $(document).height();
```

Then set the element's height to this height:

```
$("#slider1_container").height(height);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isnt working with jssor slider :(. The div is changing but the image wont be scaled to it.

Comment: Perhaps set `#slider1_container` to `display:block`? Not sure what exactly you're trying to do.