# Jssor slider: 100% width with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, width, jssor

I have a Jssor slider with 100% width that works fine everywhere except IE (tested with IE 11). Then I added the width updater script from here: [Jssor slider 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529620/jssor-slider-100-width).

This makes it work in IE, too, as long as I set the starting width of the slides with css to a size that covers most of the possible browser windows, i. e. 2500px for cases when the browser window spans over two monitors. This, however, causes big empty gaps between the actual slide's content: The slide move span is obviously definitively and session lastingly fixed by the **initial slide width** and does not adapt the current slide width.

Is there an API for adjusting the slide move span, too? What would help then is st like

```js
jssor_slider1.$SlideWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 200));
```

`$ScaleWidth` does not help, as it has effect to the slide's height (keeps aspect ration), too.

Thanks alot for your support.