# Jssor - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$ScaleWidth' of undefined

Tags: javascript, width, jssor, typeerror

I'm making my own jssor for some side-project and I stumbled across the width problem I already saw some people had problems with. I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529620/jssor-slider-100-width/21540802) to solve the problem, but after that it didn't resize in any way and just looked like before adding the code.

Using f12 in chrome helped me finding the next error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$ScaleWidth' of undefined". I don't know where this is supposed to be found. Here is how my code looks (with the fixes from above link added).

```
        <script>
        jssor_1_slider_init = function() {
            var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [
                [{b:0,d:700,y:-124,e:{y:27}}],
                [{b:0,d:700,y:-124,e:{y:27}}],
                [{b:0,d:700,y:-124,e:{y:27}}],
            ];
            var jssor_1_options = {
                $AutoPlay: true,
                $SlideDuration: 1139,
                $DragOrientation: 2,
                $PlayOrientation: 2,
                $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$OutQuint,
                $CaptionSliderOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
                    $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions
                },
                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
                },
                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
                }
            };
            var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (refSize) {
                    refSize = Math.min(refSize, 1920);
                    jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                }
                else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                if (bodyWidth)
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));
                else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
            ScaleSlider();
            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        };
    </script>
```

The width of the Jssor 1600px, as difined (not in included code here) in the div with the id "jssor_1". Also my css states all text is centered.

Someone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What's your original code that works? And what's the problem?

Comment: @jssor I tried switching out all the javascript files with the original (re-downloaded) ones, but that didn't work, so I tried changing some of the settings under the var jssor_1_slider, and that helped for some reason, I don't know why. Thanks for your time though! It's nice to see someone trying to help that actually wrote code for it ;)

Answer (score 0):

use '$ScaleWidth' on some is already deprecated so use this instead

```
'$SetScaleWidth'
```