# JSSOR slides scaling badly

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, width, jssor

We're using the jssor module on a Drupal site – you can see the dev version [here](http://sipridev.netuxosandbox.co.uk/). The problem appears on screen sizes between (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1299px). The width of the slider's container is scaling fine, but the slides inside become smaller than full width of the slider. There seems to be a problem with the slides container (not the slider container!) and the calculated value that is being used for the `transform: scale(value)` declaration on the element's style.

I have tried the $JssorSlider$.$ScaleWidth() method (recommended at [Jssor Slider 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21540802/1337386)), but that affects only the actual slider's container, which is not what's wrong here.

Comment: If anybody needs further info to be able to advise me on the topic, please do ask for it in the comments.

Comment: I haven't found the right answer, but for anyone struggling with JSSOR – try https://www.drupal.org/project/slick instead. You won't be disappointed.